# Solr query based on a string field's subset

Tags: search, solr, indexing

I'd like to send a string to Solr and let it answer with all records which are a subset of that string.

The string I would send has integer numbers separated by spaces. I wanna make solr give me all records where a specific string field is a subset of the numbers I provide as the request string.

An example...

Imagine I have an string field indexed in Solr which is in reality a set of integers separated by space. For example, let's say I have the following record's field indexed in Solr:

- "888110"
- "888110 888120"
- "888110 888120 888130"
- "888110 888120 888130 888140"
- "888110 888130 888140"
- "888110 888140"
- "888140"
- "888120 888130"

I wanna Solr to receive a query with, for example, "888110 888140" and reply with the following records:

- "888110"
- "888110 888140"
- "888140"

If I query by "888110 888120 888130" the retrieved records would be...

- "888110"
- "888110 888120"
- "888110 888120 888130"
- "888120 888130"

The retrieved records must be exactly a subset of the numbers provided as a string.

Is it possible to make Solr behave like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused why in the first example "888110" is not returned, but it is in the second example.

Anyways, if I understand generally what you are trying to do, I would be making a new field `multi valued` and use your boolean operators (AND ,OR) on the query.

eg in the schema

```
       <field name="code_string" ... />
       <field name="codes" ... multiValued="true"/>
```

so you have a document like

```
<doc>
    <arr name="codes">
       <str>811001</str>
       <str>811002</str>
    </arr>
```

and in your query

```
?=codes=811001 OR codes=811002 OR ....
```

In my experience with solr it is generally cleaner / more maintainable to sacrifice a little memory rather than creating debilitatingly complex chains of filters etc

Comment: That's right, "888110" should be in the result of the first example. My fault.

Your query doesn't seem to satisfy the proposed requirement. In the first example your query would return all records but the last one. One the second example the query would return all records.

What I would like solr to return is all records that are a subset of the num era in the request. If the record has a number that is not in the request this record should not be returned. That's Why I the requirement talos about subsets [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset).

Any new ideia?

Comment: Two points: 1) Seems to be some contradiction in your desired output and the specified behavior. You quote `If the record has a number that is not in the request this record should not be returned.` By this rationale example 1 result 2 is a contradiction to that logic. 2) my query format would return all but the second to last entry for example 2, not all.

Comment: Gotcha. OK, without mandating a new query format I cant think of a reasonable way to do this with the default Tokenizers/Filters. I would be writing a [plugin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins) for this case.